Small cap 'i' in Times New Roman, LuaLaTeX
I'm writing my master thesis on LaTeX, and I encountered a little problem with small caps. I have to use the Times New Roman font, as well as small capitals for the centuries (French conventions). But when I type : \textsc{xvii} ; I get small letters, but apparently not small capitals (the 'i' keeps its dot, see the following picture).
Here is a minimal code:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\textsc{xvii}\e siècle.

\end{document}

And here is the result (with LuaLaTeX):
Thank you very much!
PS: I tried to type 'hi' twice, but my computer seems to refuse to be polite (the 'hi' doesn't display)... Sorry :/

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Your Times New Roman system font lacks small caps and you get the warning
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n' instead on input line 9.

Select another Times-based font for small caps.
Please, note that fontenc and inputenc should not be loaded along with fontspec. There is no \e command, as far as I know; and you need {} after \ieme in order to get a space. I believe it's best to use \bsc instead of \textsc.
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[
  SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]

\begin{document}

\bsc{xvii}\ieme{} siècle.

\end{document}



Thanks a lot for your thorough answer. Sorry for the \e command, I'm so used to it that I've forgotten to give its definition (it's my 'shortcut' for \ieme{})... Duly noted for \fontenc and \inputenc; but just another question: why? (I'm only beginning with LuaLaTeX...)

Instead of \bsc, I use \scshape: {\scshape xvii}\ieme{} siècle.

@NBur That's no better than \textsc{xvii} (which is obviously preferable). What's the difference with \bsc? That with \bsc TeX won't try hyphenating the argument, which might happen with \textsc.

@PierreS. LuaLaTeX reads its input as UTF-8 anyway, so inputenc does nothing (and any other option than utf8 would break everything). The font encoding T1 is meaningless for fontspec and might lead to unexpected results, so fontenc should be used with great care and is generally to be omitted.
